# Angular 5 condition inside interpolation

Tags: html, angular, angular5, conditional-statements, interpolation

UTQG

{{ x?.a }}{{ x?.b }}{{ x?.c }}

Hello,

This is the existing piece of code. i want to display 'N/A' if x?.a=== undefined  x?.b=== undefined  x?.c === undefined. all three are strings. it should display the value of the string if any one of them has value.

This is the piece of code that i came up with

UTQG

{{ x?.a === undefined && x?.b === undefined && x?.c === undefined ? x?.a + x?.b + x?.c : 'N/A'}}

but on the html it is displaying NaN when there are values for the fields and N/A when all are undefined.

Can someone please suggest me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: there are 3 different values

Comment: You say they are all strings but from the fact that you got `NaN`, it seems there might be a number somewhere in there. `undefined` + `a number` will give you `NaN` since the sum is in fact not a number. Your requirement is also not clear. If the variables are in fact strings, from your code it looks like you're trying to combine them. Do you even need to add them or just display each one separately and show `NaN` if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I just need to show them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a `ngIf else` here. Show a element with `N/A` when all are `undefined`, else show all properties that have an value. Like so:

```html
<p *ngIf="!x?.a && !x?.b && !x?.c; else elseTemplate">
  N/A
</p>

<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  <p>
    {{ x?.a }} {{ x?.b }} {{ x?.c }}
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

**DEMO: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnhkn7?file=src/app/app.component.html)**